# ASP.NET website not allowing IE to log in with "Keep me Logged In" enabled

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer

I've googled this issue and found very little help relevant to my issue, although a lot of information about fixing a similar issue on IE10. This is occurring on IE11, both on desktop & on Windows Phone.

If I log in on IE, it works correctly; however if I tick "Keep me logged in", as soon as it redirects me to my user homepage, I'm no longer logged in. This issue does not occur in Chrome.

[image: IE11 About Screenshot]

I'm using .NET 4.5 with C# as the backend language. (ASP.NET, as mentioned)

Here's my relevant login code:

```
    else if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {   
        try
        {
            if (WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Landing", "Home", null);
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Password", "This password does not match the account you are trying to log in to.");
            }
        }
        catch (System.InvalidOperationException e)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid operation exception occured: " + e.Message);
        }
    }
```

I can confirm:

- My user details were correct
- It successfully redirects me to /Landing/Home/, implying the server believes I have successfully logged in
- I'm definitely running IE11 (See image above)

Is anyone familiar with this issue or have any idea how to correct it?

Comment: Did you clear you cookies and temporary files?  It sounds like a caching issue.

Comment: It's an issue across computers and devices, so I don't think it's a client issue.

Comment: Do you have `cookieless="UseCookies"` attribute in your `<forms>` element of web.config?

Comment: I don't have a forms element of web.config (I'm using MVC if that makes a difference); should I?

Comment: Which version of MVC are you using?  What version of the .NET framework?  Why don't you have a `<forms>` section?  how are you defining your default login page or to use Forms Authentication?

Comment: MVC Version 5, .NET 4.5 -- Oops, sorry, I *do* have one, I just didn't notice it because I was looking for one spanning multiple lines. My `<forms>` tag is just `<forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880"/>`

Comment: So add the cookieless attribute I mentioned above.

Comment: Ooh, it worked; thanks! If you post as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `cookieless="UseCookies"` to the `<forms>` element of your web.config.  It should look something like this:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="your login url" cookieless="UseCookies" ... />
</authentication>
```